# Parse error whan trying to load JSON into HTML audio tag

Tags: php, json, html

I want to use data from a JSON file in an HTML audio tag.
I am really close and able to get the data I want from the JSON but I can't load it into HTML. This is what I already tried

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/format=JSON&video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i62Zjga8JOM');
$data = json_decode($json);
$stream = $data->{'link'};
echo "<audio controls><source src= .$stream. "</audio>");
?>
```

Update: now I got this.

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rLvsC6T4YI'); // this WILL do an http request for you
$data = json_decode($json);
$stream = $data->{'link'};
echo "<audio controls><source src= $stream. '</audio>')";
?>
```

I also want to add a variable to the second line after http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/format=JSON&video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=

How can I do this?

Comment: echo "<audio controls><source src=$stream</audio>";

Comment: Wrong usage of quotes in your echo. `... src=\"$stream\"></audio>");` - also a missing `>`

Comment: `echo "<audio controls><source src= .$stream. '</audio>')";`

Comment: `$data->{'link'};` should be `$data['link'];`?

Comment: Still code is incorrect  what you added right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rLvsC6T4YI');
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$stream = $data['link'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio controls>
  <source src="<?php echo $stream;?>" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Output:- http://prntscr.com/cl4ubs

Note:- it's running audio file at my end and i am able to save it also with the default name of:-  http://prntscr.com/cl4vj8

Your second question answer:-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$variable_to_add = '1rLvsC6T4YI';
$json = file_get_contents("http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$variable_to_add");
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$stream = $data['link'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio controls>
  <source src="<?php echo $stream;?>" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks can you also explain me how i can add a variable to http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=